# Symbol lookup error since upgrading to pg 1.2.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, pg

After upgrading to pg 1.2.2 (From 1.1.4) I'm getting the following error whenever it tries to access the database:

```
ruby: symbol lookup error: /home/zifnab/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pg-1.2.2/lib/pg_ext.so: undefined symbol: PQresultMemorySize
```

Downgrading back down to 1.1.4 "fixes" the problem, but my other team members report that 1.2.2 works fine for them, so something else is going on here.

Some extra details:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic


$ ruby --version
ruby 2.6.5p114 (2019-10-01 revision 67812) [x86_64-linux]

$ rails --version
Rails 5.2.4.1

$ postgres --version
postgres (PostgreSQL) 11.6
```

I did some googling, but the only thing that I found was this heroku issue from January: https://status.heroku.com/incidents/1940

It got resolved, but they don't make any mention of what the issue was (It appears to be the *exact* same issue I'm having).

1 of my coworkers on a Mac reports he has no issues w/ this, and another on Ubuntu 17.1.0 likewise is having no issues (though he's on postgres 9.6.9, but note that our production server runs 11.6 like I am locally and again, has no issues)

Comment: Have you tried the usual reinstalling & cache clearing procedures?

Answer (score 2):

A coworker of mine found this issue: https://github.com/ged/ruby-pg/issues/332

This comment rung a bell for me:

> PQresultMemorySize is new in PostgreSQL-12, so you obviously built Ruby-pg with version 12 but try to use it on version 11. This expectingly results in a runtime linker error.

Now, I'm on postgres version 11 and haven't used 12, so I didn't think this affected me, but then I remembered I kinda-sorta-accidentally upgraded my postgres last week to 12 and then panic-downgraded it again because I didn't want it to break my local stuff (and I like it to mirror production which isn't on 12 yet). Well, seems like I might've built the pg gem against that at the same time, or something so the downgrade is giving me this error.

Uninstalling `pg` and then re-installing it fixed the issue.  It's always something simple.